# working with API json response - how do I extract nested array data and store it in a JavaScript array?

Tags: arrays, json, api, iteration, response

Below is a screenshot of the API response (from console). I need to extract the text of each "outcome" and store it in a JavaScript array.

[image]

I can iterate through the "Outcome" array, but how do I drill down further to get to the text (value) of each outcome? I feel like I'm missing something simple...

```js
function processData(myObj) { //this is the callback function for the API ajax request
  var course_learning_outcomes_array = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < myObj.catalog.Course.Outcomes_Folder.Outcome.length; k++) {
    course_learning_outcomes_array.push(myObj.catalog.Course.Outcomes_Folder.Outcome[k]);
  }
  console.log(course_learning_outcomes_array);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Outcome[k].outcome
```

It's basically just a property of the object stored into the Outcome[].

Comment: Yup, something simple!  Thank you so much @maio290. I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can access each element in the array and then simply push the `outcome` property, as follows:

```js
function processData(myObj) { //this is the callback function for the API ajax request
  var course_learning_outcomes_array = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < myObj.catalog.Course.Outcomes_Folder.Outcome.length; k++) {
    course_learning_outcomes_array.push(myObj.catalog.Course.Outcomes_Folder.Outcome[k].outcome);
  }
  console.log(course_learning_outcomes_array);
}
```